# Fixed-collapsible-left-sidebar with responsive content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to have two sidebars on the left that are fixed and collapsible, and having the main content on the right to "follow" the sidebars when they collapse/expand.

Illustration of the possible positions for sidebars and content:
[image: possible-sidebars-content-positions]

But let's proceed step by step.

1. I want a fixed sidebar on the left that is collapsible, and the main content (on the right of the sidebar) to be expanded when the sidebar is collapsed.

   The thing here is that the sidebar has a fixed position, so the content on its right has to be pushed right (with a left margin) to avoid overlap.

   I know the width of the sidebar so it's not a problem to play with CSS/JavaScript, and I have a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Pawamoy/yamm7eLh/2/

   Basically, when you click on the sidebar (bottom part), `active` class is toggled on the sidebar and `expand` class is toggled on the content. These classes will change the width of the sidebar and the left margin of the content.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#sidebar').on('click', function(e) {
       if ($(e.target).is("#sidebar")) {
         $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
         $('#content').toggleClass('expand');
       }
     });
   });
   ```
2. I want to add a second fixed and collapsible sidebar, at the right of the first one.

   But playing with toggled CSS classes will not be enough since I need to calculate which sidebar is active or not, to be able to set the left margin of the content. The left margin would be 160px when both sidebars are collapsed, 320px when only one is collapsed, and 500px when none are collapsed. Not only that but the second sidebar itself needs to be pushed back and forth on the right depending on the first sidebar width.

**Solution as I imagine it:** the content could just "follow" the element on its left (the second sidebar), without changing its left margin value. Is there a way to do that, knowing that both sidebars are fixed (they stay at the same position on the screen when the user scroll the main contents)? In other words, how can I position the second sidebar relative to the first one, and the content relative to the second sidebar, and at the same time have both sidebars "fixed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by thinking with boxes. Instead of trying to accomplish complex resizing between three side-to-side elements, I used one more layer of div. See the idea on the image below: on the left is what I was trying to do. On the right is how I solved it. I even managed to add a fixed navigation bar. I just took what I already had and used it a second time in a sub-div.

[image: solution-double-sidebar]

The key here is to **NOT** specify the `left` CSS positioning value for your fixed elements. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Pawamoy/yamm7eLh/3/